# in xAct, simplify output expression by specfic the form a function with ReplaceAll or Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, xact

in xAct, at the beginning I define a function H1(t,r) that depends on two variables using the command `DefScalarFunction`, then I want to simplify an output expression containing H1 and its derivatives by setting a specific function form of H1=t (assume H1 does not depend on r then, so derivative w.r.t r is zero).The derivative takes this form `Derivative[0, 1][H1][t, r]`. How to do that, for example, like `/.{H1[t,r]->t}` or`Simplify[...,Assumptions->{H1[t,r]==t}]` ?

the code: `(r^2*H1[t, r]*Derivative[1, 0][H1][t, r])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])`

Comment: Can you share the expression that you want to simplify? I also don't completely understand your question: it seems to me that you should try `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) using the `Derivative` expression as a left hand side pattern, rather than the much too general `H1[t, r] -> t`.

Comment: thanks, I revised the error \. in the question, expression has term like $\frac{r^2 \text{H1}(t,r) \text{H1}^{(1,0)}(t,r)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$, actually, I try the ```/.H1->(t&)```, but it can not deal with the derivative

Comment: Can you see if `(r^2*H1[t, r]*Derivative[1, 0][H1][t, r])/(2*Sqrt[Pi]) /. Derivative[1, 0][H1][t, r] -> t` does what you want?

Comment: thank you, your suggestion for writing  `/. Derivative[1, 0][H1][t, r] ->`... is feasible , also, I found `Simplify[...,Assumptions->{H1[t_,r_]:=t}]` works